# Angular - print function does not load css

Tags: css, angular, printing

I'm trying to implement a print funcion in my Angular application. This is what I've done so far:

**typescript**

```
print() {

    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open();
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
          <html>
            <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.component.css">
            </head>
            <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
          </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

**html**

```
<div id="print-section" hidden>
  <div class="red">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.red{
    color:red;
}
```

The print thing works, but it doesn't load the css. If I add a `<style>` tag inside the `write()` function it works. Why the css is not loaded? The `.css` file and the `.ts` file are in the same folder.

EDIT: thanks to @match suggestion I realized that the browser looks for the css file inside the current path, i.e. www.myurl.it/currentpage/print.component.css. Instead I want the browser looking for the file inside the sources folder, i.e. coponents/myComponent. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What does the `network` section of your browser debugger show in relation to that file. No access? 404?

Comment: You're right, I didn't think to check. It shows 404. The path is wrong...

Comment: Does your component has relative path to its css file?. It should be something like `styleUrls: ['./print.component.css']`. Assuming that your `.ts` and `.css` are in same folder.

Comment: Yes @AmitChigadani it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@media print {
      .red{
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes I was going to say, use Media Queries. ( @Rakesh - it helps if you tell the questioner what your solution is using, so they can google for more information)

Comment: Thanks. If you meant to substitute my actual css with the media query it doesn't work, because the css is not loaded correctly.